# Excel: Formula convenience

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am currently trying to pull prices from a separate spreadsheet with the following formula:

=INDEX(table_Data,MATCH(1,(A!2=table_Data[Program])*("Yes"=table_Data[Type]),0),Prices!C!2!:C!53!)

For convenience, I was wondering if it is possible to change table_Data**[**Type**]** to a cell address so I don't have to rewrite that part of the formula each time EX: table_Data[C2]

Additionally, any other tips for making my formula more efficient would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want structured references update the column name to the next column when the formula is applied to the right, then you can use the fill handle to drag the formula across. In the animated screenshot you can see the difference between dragging the fill handle and copying the formula to the right with Ctrl-R

[image]

Unfortunately, in your scenario that would also change the reference to `table_Data[Program]` to the next column to the right.

So you may want to drop structured references and use old-fashioned cell references instead (or a mix of both)

I assume that the ! signs in your formula should really be $ signs, no? In any case, if you use cell addresses, you don't need to use the table name.

Comment: Yes you are correct i meant to type in $